# C sscanf behaviour

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am trying to understand `sscanf` behaviour for that I have executed below two program.

```
void main()
{
        char *a = "225.311";
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        sscanf(a, "%d.3%d", &x, &y);
        printf("x is %d, y is %d\n", x, y);
}
```

output is

```
x is 255, y is 11
```

Below program is not working as per my expectation.

```
void main()
{
        char *a = "225.311";
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        sscanf(a, "%d5.3%d", &x, &y);
        printf("x is %d, y is %d\n", x, y);
}
```

I am expecting `25,11`, but the output is

```
x is 255, y is 0
```

I am expecting `sscanf` behaviour should exact same as sprintf in reverse manner. But its not working in my second program. If the format specifed is `%d5.3%d`, then it has to consider `5` as delimeter. But its not considering and reading all digits for `x`, and then dot is not matching with `5.3%d` so it quits there.

Can somebody please explain this.

Comment: Always check for return value of `[s]scanf`. If it's not equal to number of placeholders you've used then you'll be aware that some errors occured.

Comment: Read the docs or man page for `scanf`, do not assume... This family of text parsing functions has a lot of power, but I'd say that power comes with more responsibility than it is worth, not to mention defaults may be unintuitive from user point of view. It's often better to read a line with standard C `fgets` or GNU/POSIX2008 `getline`, then parse with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `%d` conversion specifier means `sscanf` will keep reading from the buffer pointed to by `a` till it encounters a non-numeric character in the buffer. This means that `%d` will consume up till `225` in the string literal `"225.311"` in your second example.

> If the format specifed is `%d5.3%d`, then it has to consider 5 as
>   delimeter.

No, that's not true. `5` in the format string means `sscanf` will match it exactly (after reading an int) in the buffer it reads from. If it fails to match it, then `sscanf` will return and the value of `y` is left unchanged. You can check for this by storing the result of `sscanf`. The return value is equal to the number of input items successfully matched and assigned.

```
char *a = "225.311";
int x = 0, y = 0;
int retval = sscanf(a, "%d5.3%d", &x, &y);
printf("%d\n", retval); // prints 1
```

However, note that if the sequence of numeric characters in the buffer is too long to fit into an `int`, then the behaviour is undefined because of signed integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using a different format and checking the results of `sscanf()`.  Also to distinguish fractions like "0.001" and "0.1", note positions.

```
const char *a = "225.0311";
int ipart = 0;
unsigned fractionpart;
int n1, n2;
if (sscanf(a, "%d.%n%u%n", &ipart, &n1, &fractionpart, &n2) != 2) {
  Handle_BadInput();
}

printf("ipart is %d, fractionpart is %0*u\n", ipart, n2 - n1, fractionpart);
// ipart is 225, fractionpart is 0311
```

As @ajay discusses, `"%d5.3%d"` looks for an `int`, then `"5.3"` then another `int`.